# Why does virtual directory appear in url using VS2012 but not appear in VS2015?

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple website (as oppose to a web application template) I created in VS2008. I upgraded to VS2012 and everything appears fine. Mainly, concerned with url while navigating to website inside Visual Studio.

In VS2012, my url works as expected

```
http://localhost:54106/urlweb
```

However, if I try to open and navigate inside VS2015 I won't get the virtual directory

```
http://localhost:54106
```

Any ideas? The solution doesn't require an upgrade when I open in VS2015 either.

**Basically, trying to get the following article to work in VS2015. Please note: Using .Net Framework 3.5 SP1**

[How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Good question. I encountered the same in VS2013. My website didn't work because it was dependent on the virtual directory being a specific string. I fixed it by changing the website to remove the dependency, which is an improvement overall. But I would still like to know if you can tell VS what it should be...